# Scattered data interpolation in ILNumerics

Tags: c#, interpolation, ilnumerics

I'm looking for a way to visualize scattered data with interpolation on a heatmap. Matlab's griddata function solves this with nearest, linear and cubic interpolation by internally using Delaunay triangulation.

Does ILNumerics have a scattered data interpolation function similar to griddata, or is there a math library for C# which does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the closest ILNumerics can bring you is regression: fit a function to the data and use the function to create a surface. In order to fit a function, you have the following options in ILNumerics:

linsolve, ridge_regression, optimpdl (still in beta)

The surface is than straightforward: new ILSurface().

But there is currently no such function like ‘griddata’ in ILNumerics.